# Real-time reporting Tomcat Webserver

Tags: java, tomcat, reporting, monitoring

I'd like to monitor my Tomcat Webserver in real-time.

**e.g.** 
*each 5 seconds a script/program tells me how*

> a) many users currently online
>   b) how many requests in total
>   c) how
>   many megabytes transferred
>   d) avg. response time
>    e) how many java
>   objects have been initialized since then.

Is that possbible? If yes, using what framework/API?

Answer (score 1):

You could expose Mbeans through JMX.  They can accrue the statistics you are looking for (it's up to you to define the statistics and how they are aggregated) and then you can inspect them using jconsole any time you wish.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, I downloaded a command-line tool for JMX (http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm/). Using the command "beans" I can see all the MBeans of my Tomcat server. Do you have any idea what MBeans I should look into further to gain info about performance?